# query_posts thumbnail condition

Tags: query-posts, post-thumbnails

I am trying to call in all posts in the current category, showing their thumbnail or 'featured image'. The code below does not work, it throws out a syntax error...

```
            <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
            <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {
                $cat = $category->cat_ID; }
                query_posts('orderby=date&cat=' . $cat . '&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1''); 
            ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="page-thumb-wrap-single">
                        <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    the_post_thumbnail();
                                } else {
                                        echo '<img src="#" alt="Something Went Wrong?" title="Sorry - Something went wrong?" />';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

...however, this code does retrieve the thumbnail;

```
            <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
            <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {
                $cat = $category->cat_ID; }
                query_posts('orderby=date&cat=' . $cat . '&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1''); 
            ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="page-thumb-wrap-single">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can someone explain to me what it is i am doing wrong and why this occurs? It may also help me answer another question;

How can i create a condition inside this call to say 'if post has tag... do... if post has other tag... do...'

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two single quote marks (after the number 1) in this line (of the top posted code section) seem to be causing the error - there should only be one single quote; shown below:

```
query_posts('orderby=date&cat=' . $cat . '&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1');
```

it is just puzzling that your other code (with the same error) alledegly does work (?)

if this is not the cause: what was the exact syntax error message?

Comment: That double single quote mark seemed to be making things break - but only with the second code? Not it is corrected, there dont seem to be any errors, so thanks!